# Mule Database Query to JSON output nesting not working?

Tags: json, mule

I am new to using Mule and having a problem with outputting nested Json. I am using mule 3.3 and the GUI interface. I add the database component to my flow and run some simple SQL including a 'one to many' join. After this I added an 'Oject to Json' component, the problem is the resulting JSON is flat it does not nest the 'one to many' elements. For example I expect:

```
{
"firstName": "John",
"phoneNumber": [
    {
        "type": "home",
        "number": "212 555-1234"
    },
    {
        "type": "fax",
        "number": "646 555-4567"
    }
]
}
```

I actually get:

```
{
 "firstName": "John",
 "type": "home",
 "number": "212 555-1234"
}
```

Can anyone give me any direction on what I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Since you haven't posted your configuration, it's hard to tell exactly what you're doing. Anyways...*

The select query returns a flat view of the users data. If you want to create a structured representation of it, you'll have to create a transformer to do so, prior to serializing to JSON.

Alternatively, you can use an ORM to map your data to objects then serialize these objects to JSON.